# apache2 service is active, but apache2 cannot reload

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a VPS with Ubuntu and Apache, in which there are several web application sites, in order not to affect the users when I add a site I use the "sudo service apache2 reload", but from one moment to another it started to mark an error

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

---

$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
└─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code)

I have checked the status and the configuration syntax and everything is in order, I have not restarted or reinstalled apache so as not to affect users.

Has anyone been through this?

Comment: What about **journalctl -xe** ?? Does the /var/log/apache2/error.log tells you something? What about /var/log/syslog or /var/log/daemon.log?